# Lucene.net parse Fields to create a LIKE equivalent search

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

I've found Lucene to be fantastic so far, but I'm having a few issues with duplicating a LIKE equivalent search.

In an application I'm working on I need the option of a "simplified" (LIKE) search and an advanced (full text) search. The data is user based (name, location etc) so not huge reams of text.

In the past I'd simply create a SQL query which concatenated db field names, surrounding the terms with wildcards. I could do that in my application, bypassing lucene for simple searches of the user data - but it would be nice to use lucene.

I've tried regex searches

```
var query = QueryParser.Escape(_query);
var search = new RegexQuery(new Term("name",string.Concat(".*", _query, ".*")));
```

but they only work on one column.

One idea I had was to tokenise each field to produce something similar to a full text search e.g:

name: Paul

so I create the following name fields...

Paul
Pau
Pa
aul
ul
au

Would this defeat the point of using lucene over a LIKE SQL search? Would it actually produce the results I want?

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

**Edit:**

Slightly modifying the code in this question:

[Elegant way to split string into 2 strings on word boundaries to minimize length difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680346/elegant-way-to-split-string-into-2-strings-on-word-boundaries-to-minimize-length)

to produce this tokeniser:

```
    private IEnumerable<string> Tokeniser(string _item)
    {
        string s = _item;

        const int maxPrefixLength = 10;
        const int maxSuffixLength = 10;
        const int minStemLength = 1;

        var tokens = new List<string>();


        for (int prefixLength = 0; (prefixLength + minStemLength <= s.Length) && (prefixLength <= maxPrefixLength); prefixLength++)
            for (int suffixLength = 0; (suffixLength + prefixLength + minStemLength <= s.Length) && (suffixLength <= maxSuffixLength); suffixLength++)
            {
                string prefix = s.Substring(0, prefixLength);
                string suffix = s.Substring(s.Length - suffixLength);
                string stem = s.Substring(prefixLength, s.Length - suffixLength - prefixLength);

                if (prefix.Length > 1)
                    if (!tokens.Contains(prefix))
                        tokens.Add(prefix);

                if (suffix.Length > 1)
                    if (!tokens.Contains(suffix))
                        tokens.Add(suffix);

                if (stem.Length > 1)
                    if (!tokens.Contains(stem))
                        tokens.Add(stem);
            }

        return tokens;
    }
```

The search results do give the equivalent of a LIKE search. My "user" table will only ever be 9000 entities in size - so for me at least, this might fit my needs.

Are there any downfalls of doing this (except for a much larger lucene index?)

Comment: You can try `SingleCharTokenAnalyzer` at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/branches/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g/src/contrib/Core/Analysis/Ext/Analysis.Ext.cs

Comment: I've found this Analyzer to be very slow on longer fields.

Comment: Hi L.B. I'll take a look! The string parser I posted above is working really well. I wouldn't use it for fields with more than 5-6 words perhaps, but for name fields, it's great. I modified it slightly to break apart tokens at spaces and simply store the whole name, then analyse not store, the tokenised bits of name in other 'name' fields etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character-based n-gram (NGramTokenizer, NGramTokenFilter, EdgeNGramTokenizer and EdgeNGramTokenFilter should provide the functionality you need.